# List Roles on cassandra getting NoHostAvailable on one DataCentre

Tags: replication, configuration, cassandra

I have a 2 DC cluster, 'main' and 'bi' with a replication factor of 3 and a NetworkTopologyStrategy.

When I call `LIST HOSTS;` in cqlsh, my `bi` datacentre lists all the roles appropriately, but I get a `NoHostAvailable:` response from nodes in my `main` datacentre.

Any ideas?

Here is the keyspace description for the `system_auth` table --

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'bi': '3', 'main': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

All of my cassandra-rackdc.properties files correctly list their `dc` and `rack`.

As an aside, all `selects` work on all nodes.

Comment: What does `nodetool describecluster` say about your schema agreement?  Also, is the cluster in the cloud or on bare metal?